# MySQL Ajuda com INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

**Fala pessoal, boa noite! Estou quebrando a cuca aqui, gostaria de saber se as questões 3 e 4 estão corretas e como ficaria estruturado a sintaxe caso fosse responder elas utilizando INNER JOIN e se ele é mais indicado.**

Nós temos um sistema de gerenciamento de professores e alunos em uma escola baseada em um banco de dados MySQL, que possui 3 tabelas (professor, aluno e relacionamento) com o seguinte conteúdo:

[image: tabela professor e aluno]

[image: tabela relacionamento]

Todas as tabelas têm um índice primário chamado "id", que identifica cada registro de maneira exclusiva. A tabela "relacionamento" é aquela que relaciona os professores aos alunos.
Precisamos que você construa os comandos necessários do MySQL para obter as seguintes informações:

**1.    Nome do professor de ciencias**

```
SELECT * FROM professor WHERE assinatura=ciencias;
```

**2.    Conte quantos alunos estão na escola**

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM aluno;
```

**3.    Lista de nomes com todos os alunos do professor de ciências, levando em conta que os únicos dados que temos sobre o professor é que a assinatura dele é "ciencias".**

```
SELECT *
FROM aluno a,
           professor p,
           relacionamento r
WHERE p.assinatura = 'ciencias'
AND p.id = r.professor_id
AND r.aluno_id = a.id
```

**4. Lista de alunos que não estão na aula de ciências, levando em conta que os únicos dados que temos sobre o professor é que a assinatura dele é "ciência".**

```
SELECT *
FROM aluno a,
           professor p,
           relacionamento r
WHERE p.assinatura != 'ciencias'
AND p.id = r.professor_id
AND r.aluno_id = a.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Nome do professor de ciencias

   SELECT * FROM professor WHERE assinatura='ciencias';

Faltaram as aspas.

3. Lista de nomes com todos os alunos do professor de ciências, levando em conta que os únicos dados que temos sobre o professor é que a assinatura dele é "ciencias". Utilizando junção:

   SELECT *
   FROM aluno a INNER JOIN relacionamento r ON (r.aluno_id = a.id)
   INNER JOIN professor p ON (p.id = r.professor_id)
   WHERE p.assinatura = 'ciencias'
4. Lista de alunos que não estão na aula de ciências, levando em conta que os únicos dados que temos sobre o professor é que a assinatura dele é "ciência". Utilizando junção:

   SELECT *
   FROM aluno a INNER JOIN relacionamento r ON (r.aluno_id = a.id)
   INNER JOIN professor p ON (p.id = r.professor_id)
   WHERE p.assinatura = 'ciencia'

Se bem que na sua tabela acima não existe um registro com assinatura = 'ciencia' (existe com 'ciencias').

Answer (score 0):

Não, está errado.
Até funciona, mas depois de 92 passou a se usar INNER join

3. SELECT * FROM aluno a INNER JOIN relacionamento r ON (r.aluno_id = a.id) INNER JOIN professor p ON (p.id = r.professor_id) WHERE p.assinatura = 'ciencias'
4. SELECT * FROM aluno a INNER JOIN relacionamento r ON (r.aluno_id = a.id) INNER JOIN professor p ON (p.id = r.professor_id) WHERE p.assinatura <> 'ciencias'